# Knowledge__kav object's standard fields in Metadata API file issue

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, knowledge

Is there anyone has tried to retrieve the Knowledge_kav object's standard fields via Metadata API before?
Seems to me that it is not available for the Knowledge obj. When I use:

```
<types>
<members>Knowledge__kav</members>
<name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

I was expecting to get the standard fields but none of them was retrieved. Any idea?

Comment: they are definitely retrievable as I can see them in Gearset that uses MDAPI under the covers. Did you try `KnowledgeArticleVersion`?

Comment: Thank you a lot @cropredy . I could see them on KnowledgeArticleVersion. In my case, I need to deploy a help text of a standard field. But It doesn't seem on the metadata file of the field(IsVisibleInPkb). When I add the help text on Knowledge_kav through object manager, should it be reflected on KnowledgeArticleVersion?